# Check condition within table possibly self-join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, self-join

I have a *users* table with many columns however I am trying to use the below 2 columns to fetch the users do not have expired = 1

The query should return only user 2. Any help is much appreciated.

```
user_id  expired 
1          1
1          0
2          0
2          0
3          1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you have an answer, but if you are just looking for a list of single user_id's this might work a little more efficiently:

```
select user_id 
from users
GROUP BY user_id
having MAX(expired) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `not in` like below :

```
select * from users where user_id 
                           not in(select distinct user_id from users where expired = 1);
```

See [SQL Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c6e09/1)